# Sendig Emojis from MQL4 to Telegram Bot

Tags: telegram-bot, emoji, mql4, mql

I'm trying to send Emojis to telegram bot. I managed to send text message but i don't know how to send Emoji.

I tried the below code but doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
string x_emoji="\x1F4B";
string text = "Order modified: "+x_emoji+" \n" + TimeToString( TimeLocal() ); 
SendTelegramMessage( TAPIUrl, Token, Chat_Id, text , fileName_Pic );
```